# How to solve setting a value to true inside a foreach loop while also setting the value to true on the outside of the loop in Cypress

Tags: foreach, cypress, boolean-expression

I am having some issues trying to solve this problem. What I'd like to happen is if the forEach loop does NOT find the first text after running through all the cells. Then the final if block on the outside should run, and assert that the first text cell was not found.

Thank you :-)

```
Cypress.Commands.add("aCommand", (Locator, firstCellText, secondCellText) => {

  let firstCellTextFound = false
  cy.get("aDifferentLocator").find(Locator).each($cell => {
    let text = $cell.text()

    if (text.includes(firstCellText)) {
      cy.wrap($cell).next().should("have.text", secondCellText)

      firstCellTextFound = true
    }
  })

  if(firstCellTextFound == false)
  {
    expect(firstCellTextFound).to.be.true
  }
})
```

Comment: If this is a table you are searching within you might benefit from a different approach. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to verify that some fields are what I expect them to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your outside `if` block is synchronous code, while your `cy.get()` command is asynchronous, so the `if` block will execute while the `cy.get().each()` is still running. Wrapping that final `if` in a `.then()` block should solve your problem.

```js
let firstCellTextFound = false
cy.get("aDifferentLocator").find(Locator).each($cell => {
  ... code ...
}).then(() => {
  if(firstCellTextFound == false) {
    expect(firstCellTextFound).to.be.true
  }
})
```